# Event based handler using cached variable without global scope

Tags: javascript

I have a function handler that runs with a specific signature.

For Example:

```
const config = {
  external: () => {
    // do something
  }
}
```

This handler can fire `n` number of times. However, I'd like to have a variable be used within this handler and only fire once and be cached. I don't want to have the variable live outside of config in the global scope. How can I have the variable be defined and cached for subsequent calls without using global scope?

To make matters kind of worse, the thing that creates this cached variable is a promise.

Comment: You can do that by creating an instance of config. Then the instance can retain state. You will have to keep a reference to the instance somewhere though!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the handler into an immediately invoked function expression and store the cached promise in the closure:

```
const config = (() => {

  let cachedPromise;

  return () => {

    if (!cachedPromise) {
      cachedPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(5);
        }, 1000)
      });
    }

    cachedPromise.then((cache) => {
      console.log(`Cached value ${cache}`);
    })
  };

})();
```

Comment: I can't do this, the config is exported as an object directly.

Comment: I see, sorry, hadn't realized this constraint.